# Why can't Nginx POST to my Perl backend?

Tags: perl, sockets, cgi, nginx, fastcgi

EDIT: So I just found out that GET methods indeed work, but POST methods however do not work! That might be significant.

So I am on Debian Etch, running Nginx. Nginx does not normally serve cgi/pl files so I have followed a guide to get my backend working.

http://technotes.1000lines.net/?p=23

My backend works fine on Apache but I had to install a module working with nginx (lib-www).

It now works, but for some reason, POST/GET methods don't work.... To give an example, my backend is set up to accept Product SKU's in the url, and it just adds it to cart when you do it. Now, if I were to directly type in this url with this added value, it works fine, adds it to cart, everything works beautifully....

However, when I add a product to the cart, all my product pages are setup to submit to my backend. It submits the exact same value I could type into my browser window, except it does not work (in contrast to just typing it into my url bar which DOES work).

Now I'm thinking the perl wrapper code I'm using is slightly wrong or something? It is here:

http://technotes.1000lines.net/fastcgi-wrapper.pl

I only made a couple of changes... I merely made a folder that it wants to install the socket in (but maybe it should be going in a different folder all together), and in my nginx conf I basically have it like this:

```
location ~ ^/cgi-bin/.*\.pl$ {
  gzip off;
  fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/nginx/perl_cgi-dispatch.sock;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /www/blah.com$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
```

My params are the same as they are in the article, and I only have the default mime type setup. Any ideas on why this is not working? I would be willing to provide any extra information you need as well.

Answer (score 1):

This particular fastcgi-wrapper.pl script was modified by Denis S. Filimonov to handle POSTS requests properly. You can read more about it at: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/145858